# Symfony2 exception

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony2. I am creating a simple page for "Hello {Name}" and using WAMP. and my routing.yml is as follows

```
projectnew_bundle:
    resource: "@projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /start
```

and my @projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml is as follows (projectnew_bundle is the namespace for \project\new_bundle  in src folder) :

```
projectnew_bundle_hello:
    pattern:  start/hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: projectnew_bundle:Start:hello }
```

I have also registered the bundle projectnew_bundle in AppKernel.php using `"new project\new_bundle\projectnew_bundle()"` syntax. My `\src\project\new_bundle\projectnew_bundle.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace project\new_bundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class projectnew_bundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

But, when I try to load the following URL : "http://localhost/symfony_project/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/start/hello/Riten" , it gives the 500 internal server error:

> Cannot load resource `"@projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"`. Make sure the `"projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"` bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.

Comment: To be sure, did you clear the cache (app/console cache:clear -env=dev)

Comment: I didn't use console.. But, I have cleared the Symfony/app/cache folder manually..

Comment: Please guys give me the solution to fix the problem

Comment: And btw. start using CamelCase not underscore_case

Answer (score 3):

Try removing type: annotation from routing.yml

EDIT:

Your app/cofig/routing.yml has

```
projectnew_bundle:
    resource: "@projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /start
```

*Note: I removed `type:     annotation`

So you set prefix `/start` on any route included in `projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

Then your `@projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` has:

```
projectnew_bundle_hello:
    pattern:  start/hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: projectnew_bundle:Start:hello }
```

which creates the route `projectnew_bundle_hello` with the pattern `start/hello/{name}` adding the prefix from `app/config/routing.yml`  your final route is `/startstart/hello/{name}` and not `/start/hello/{name}` as you are expecting.

If you want your expected route to work you can remove `start` from `@projectnew_bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`.

The command `php app/console router:debug` will show you what your routes actually are.

Comment: Now, I removed the type: annotation from routing.yml ... and it is now showing 404 not found error: 'No route found for "GET /start/hello/Riten" '.. So, what should I do now to solve this??

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.. You really helped me to solve this problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change to type: annotation you have to change the resource path to the controller path.

```
projectnew_bundle:
resource: "@projectnew_bundle/Controller"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /start
```